# Starting n Spark worker nodes corresponding to n+1 slurm tasks

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hpc, slurm

I am using an HPC cluster where the job manager is SLURM. On getting 6 slurm tasks using the following command:

```
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=3
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
```

I would like to have 1 Spark Master and 5 Spark Worker nodes deployed.

Currently, I am using a script where one master and one slave would be deployed in on node (using a single Slurm task) and the rest of the tasks would deploy just one worker node each. How would I modify this script to deploy multiple worker nodes per task? In the current script, the worker nodes would be assigned a predefined static port number such that only the ip address along with the port number could differentiate the worker. For the same reason, no more than one worker could be uniquely identified in a single node. Therefore the current script is useful only if the --ntasks-per-node is 1.

How would I dynamically allocate ports making sure that the rest of the script would work as expected?

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -J bda-job
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=28
#SBATCH --time=01:30:00
#SBATCH -p batch
#SBATCH --qos qos-batch
#SBATCH -o %x-%j.log

### Load latest available Spark
module load devel/Spark

### If you do not wish tmp dirs to be cleaned
### at the job end, set below to 0
export SPARK_CLEAN_TEMP=1

### START INTERNAL CONFIGURATION

## CPU and Memory settings
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK}
export DAEMON_MEM=4096
export NODE_MEM=$((4096*${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK}-${DAEMON_MEM}))
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=${DAEMON_MEM}m
export SPARK_NODE_MEM=${NODE_MEM}m

## Set up job directories and environment variables
export BDA_HOME_DIR="$HOME/bda"
export SPARK_JOB_DIR="$BDA_HOME_DIR/spark-jobs"
export SPARK_JOB="$BDA_HOME_DIR/spark-jobs/${SLURM_JOBID}"
mkdir -p "${SPARK_JOB}"

export SPARK_HOME=$EBROOTSPARK
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=${SPARK_JOB}
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=${SPARK_JOB}
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=9080
export SPARK_SLAVE_WEBUI_PORT=9081
export SPARK_INNER_LAUNCHER=${SPARK_JOB}/spark-start-all.sh
export SPARK_MASTER_FILE=${SPARK_JOB}/spark_master

export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DRFA"

export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--conf spark.executor.memory=${SPARK_NODE_MEM} --conf spark.worker.memory=${SPARK_NODE_MEM}"


## Generate spark starter-script
cat << 'EOF' > ${SPARK_INNER_LAUNCHER}
#!/bin/bash
## Load configuration and environment
source "$SPARK_HOME/sbin/spark-config.sh"
source "$SPARK_HOME/bin/load-spark-env.sh"
if [[ ${SLURM_PROCID} -eq 0 ]]; then
    ## Start master in background
    export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=$(hostname)
    MASTER_NODE=$(scontrol show hostname ${SLURM_NODELIST} | head -n 1)

    echo "spark://${SPARK_MASTER_HOST}:${SPARK_MASTER_PORT}" > "${SPARK_MASTER_FILE}"

    "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class" org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master \
        --ip $SPARK_MASTER_HOST                                           \
        --port $SPARK_MASTER_PORT                                         \
        --webui-port $SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT &

    ## Start one slave with one less core than the others on this node
    export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=$((${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK}-1))
    "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class" org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker \
       --webui-port ${SPARK_SLAVE_WEBUI_PORT}                             \
       spark://${MASTER_NODE}:${SPARK_MASTER_PORT} &

    ## Wait for background tasks to complete
    wait
else
    ## Start (pure) slave
    MASTER_NODE=spark://$(scontrol show hostname $SLURM_NODELIST | head -n 1):${SPARK_MASTER_PORT}
    "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-class" org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker \
       --webui-port ${SPARK_SLAVE_WEBUI_PORT}                             \
       ${MASTER_NODE}
fi
EOF
chmod +x ${SPARK_INNER_LAUNCHER}

## Launch SPARK and wait for it to start
srun ${SPARK_INNER_LAUNCHER} &
while [ -z "$MASTER" ]; do
    sleep 5
    MASTER=$(cat "${SPARK_MASTER_FILE}")
done
### END OF INTERNAL CONFIGURATION
```